# link_to send parameters along with the url and grab them on target page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i have a link on a page that takes the user to another URL and passes along a parameter and on the target url how can we pick up that parameter.

usually I add links like following:

```
 <%= link_to "Add Product", '/pages/product' %>
```

But how can I send parameters along with this url? Can I pick them in the target action by `using params[:parm_name]`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just add them to link:

```
<%= link_to "Add Product", '/pages/product?param1=value1&param2=value2' %>
```

and in controller:

```
param1 = params[:param1] # "value1"
param2 = params[:param2] # "value2"
```

If you use helper methods for routes (for example `company_path`), then you can add hash of params, so this two should be similar:

```
<%= link_to "Add Product", new_product_path(:param1 => "value1", :param2 => "value2") %>
<%= link_to "Add Product", "/products/new?param1=value1&param2=value2" %>
```

From [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597):

```
link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
# => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>

link_to "Ruby on Rails search", :controller => "searches", :query => "ruby on rails"
# => <a href="/searches?query=ruby+on+rails">Ruby on Rails search</a>

link_to "Nonsense search", searches_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux")
# => <a href="/searches?foo=bar&amp;baz=quux">Nonsense search</a>
```

Comment: oh...i thought there would be a more railsy way to do it

Comment: @Omnipresent there is rails way, but you should use rails helper methods for paths/urls, not type address by hand

Comment: there is. define :controller, :action and all other params in a single hash.

Comment: @Eimantas , could you add an answer that has an example with :controller, :action and :params?
That would help me greatly.

Comment: @BookOfGreg http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to/

    `link_to "Profile", :controller => "profiles", :action => "show", :foo => "bar", :baz => "quux"

# => <a href="/profiles/show?baz=quux&foo=bar">Profile</a>`

Comment: I added the output of rake routes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more rails-y way of doing it.

```
<%= link_to 'Link Text', 
{controller: 'controller/name', action: 'action_name', query: params[:query]},
method: 'get', 
:class=>'link_styling' %>
```

You need to reference your params in the hash defining the link. It also needs to be a GET method. Styling is optional of course.

This should really be here too: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to