# Ruby on Rails link_to route path while preserving original query string parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper

I have a URL like so http://example.com/?sort=pop

In my view I am using `link_to category.name, categories_path(category)`

How can I preserve any query string parameters that might already exist on the requesting URL?

So the final link URL would be http://example.com/categories/1?sort=pop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= link_to category.name, category_path(category, params) %>
```

Should do the trick

Take care that the default route helper to access a specific Category is `category_path`. Singular since it's for only one category, makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Anthony's solution almost worked for me. However, it didn't like just having `params` as one of the passed through variables. Instead, I had to add `params:` or `:params =>` to the link. It works just find for me now.

`<%= link_to "XLS ", users_path(format: "xls", params: params)  %>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to category.name, category_path(category,
  request.parameters.merge({:new_params => 42}) ) %>
```

This should link to the right path, preserve existing parameters and add any new params you might have.

[Rails: Preserving GET query string parameters in link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762430/rails-preserving-get-query-string-parameters-in-link-to/4174493#4174493)