# Rails Sunspot issue with counting and when showing items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm working on a open-source project, [BTC-Stores](http://www.btc-stores.com), and I think I found a issue in [Rails Sunspot gem](http://sunspot.github.io/).

In my architecture I have `Item`s, and each Item have one `Country` and one `Category`. The facets and the search by filters already is working ([thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961485/rails-sunspot-filter-facet-issue-with-url-deleting-old-get-params)), but I found a strange thing in count and mainly when showing my items.

**First of all, if I go to `rails console` and type the following, it prints:**

```
Item.count # => 329
```

### First strange thing:

When I search, Sunspot shows me more than 329 stores. See the page "breadcrumb" and understand:

[image]
What can be making this problem?

### Second strange thing:

When I Search, the first page is (almost) okay, like you saw above. But when I go to "Page 2", I receive:

[image]

What means that none store was found by Sunspot search. Again, another "but": when I go to "Page 67", the last page, it's working again! (and still working for the last pages)

[image]

**So, can you understand what's the problem without see any code? Anyway, thanks for help!**

Comment: (P.S: The "stores" without images isn't a problem [well, it's, but I don't want be answered about that])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer found!

I solved this issue reindexing Sunspot, as [documentation said here](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects). So, if you have the same problem I had, try run in Terminal:

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

Well, here solved all issues. :)