# Passing parameters to url -ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, parameters

Hy, i have problem with my aplication. On my Webpage i have instruction: <%= link_to "English", :locale=>'en'%> and it work good when I am on the main page, but if I have in URL many parameters, I have error, because after click this link I have only one parametr. For example:
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=asd&locale=pl&commit=Szukaj
After click:
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/search?locale=en
Somebody know how i can solve this problem?
In layout i have this line:

```
     <% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
  <%= link_to "English", :locale=>'en'%>

<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Polski", :locale=>'pl'%>
```

It works good when I want to go to: static_pages/home or static_pages/contact, but if I have subpage, which require parameters from form and i want to on it change language, I have error. 
For example i have this form:

```
<%= form_tag(static_pages_search_path, :method => "get" ) do %>
            <%= text_field(:post, :title, size: 20, :name =>"search", :style => "color: #C0C0C0; margin-top: 10px;", :placeholder => t('widok.wyszukiwarka.tekst'),:required => true,:minlength=>"3")%>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'locale', language  %>
          <%= submit_tag t('widok.wyszukiwarka.przycisk'),data: { disable_with: t('widok.wyszukiwarka.przycisk_czekaj') } %>
          <% end %>
```

where language=I18n.locale.

When I click sumbit_tag all works, but if I want to change language on this subpage i have error because URL have only one parametr: locale and hasn't parametr search and commit

Comment: Please share a minimal amount of relevant code. Unless you do that, no one can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: Preserving GET query string parameters in link\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762430/rails-preserving-get-query-string-parameters-in-link-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Kristján for help. I use `<%= link_to "English", params.merge({:locale=>'en'})%>` and now aplication works:)