# Appending text onto current URL through link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say the current page a user is on is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?direction=asc&sort=title
```

Its sorted ascending, by title.

Now lets say I have a search engine, that if you searched for "chicken" for example, the url might be:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts?direction=asc&search=chicken&sort=title
```

But instead of searching, I'd like to make a link such as `<a href="CODE HERE">Show all results for chicken</a>` which appends &search=chicken to url, or if search already has a value, replaces it.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link\_to the current page plus/merged with a param](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535908/link-to-the-current-page-plus-merged-with-a-param) . This came first, but the other was probably better posed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add querystring parameters to link\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `link_to` function without a specified controller/action. Just provide the arguments you want and a URL will be created for the current page plus those parameters.

Note that you will need to use the existing `params` hash and merge in your additional `:search` item, otherwise your `direction` and `sort` arguments will be removed from the URL. Also, if there is an existing `params[:search]` item, it will be overwritten by the merge.

```
<%= link_to "Show all results for chicken", params.merge({:search => "chicken"}) %>
```