# detect which link in a view was pressed from inside a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a method inside my controller which is called by Link_to which detects which user called the controller to render out a different view but I need to detect which individual link was pressed not just which user called the controller

Comment: What do you mean, which link? They'll either route to different controllers/actions, or have a parameter indicating what differentiates the link from the others. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I need them to point to the same action for example I want two buttons one that displays results which have the approved attribute as true and one which displays results which have the approved attribute as false, they both call the index action in the controller but I need a way to differentiate.

basically how to pass that parameter you mentioned to the controller?

Comment: so that on the controller I can read the parameter in and say if parameter == x then render this particular view

Comment: Just add a parameter; not sure what the issue is. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to).

Comment: would you mind providing an example using this:
<%= link_to 'View Previous Absences', :controller=> "absences", :action=>"index" %> I don't know if it's different because I'm not using a path

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: like this? <%= link_to 'View Previous Absences', absences_path(:completed => '1') %> if so how do I access the completed parameter on the other side?

Comment: Perfect, think I've got it all together, thank you very much

Comment: Cool; glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the same controller/action do this.

```
 link_to 'home', root_path(:link => 'one')
```

then for the next link

```
 link_to 'home', root_path(:link => 'two')
```

now in your controller

```
params[:link]
```

will give the link name