# params.merge and cross site scripting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xss

I'm using [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org) to identify security issues. It's flagging up any links which use `params.merge` as a cross site scripting vulnerability. How can I sanitize something like the following?

```
  - @archives.each do |archive|
    =  link_to "FTP", params.merge(:action => :ftp, :archive => archive, :recipient => "company")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should create a new hash based on only the elements of `params` which you expect and wish to allow to be a part of the `FTP` link and use **that** to merge your additional parameters.

What you have allows me to add whatever I want to that `FTP` link by modifying the querystring, opening up the door to security vulnerabilities. By building a hash for use in place of the `params` in the `params.merge(...` you're effectively whitelisting expected querystring components for use in the template you're rendering.

---

As a `GET` example, if you expect a URL like

```
/some/path?opt1=val1&opt2=val2
```

your controller action you might do

```
@cleaned_params = { opt1: params[:opt1], opt2: params[:opt2] }
@cleaned_params.merge! action: :ftp, archive: archive, recipient: :company
```

And then pass @cleaned_params to the `link_to`

```
=  link_to "FTP", @cleaned_params
```

This way if I manually enter a URL like

```
/some/path?opt1=val1&opt2=val2&maliciousopt=somexss
```

The `params[:maliciousopt]` will never make it into your `FTP` `link_to` in your view.

The same behaviour applies to `POST` requests, only to be malicious I might add a couple fields to the form before submitting it

```
<input type="hidden" name="maliciousopt" value="somexss" />
```

Comment: Or, in fact, in my case here I can simply remove the params.merge and the required params get passed in without any interference from a user.

Comment: Wouldn't an attacker just have to replace some of the acceptable params with their malicious script and get it stuck in the page either way?