# Canonical way to insert extension into URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a URL in a Rails application that can look like a simple `/resource` or a more complex `/resource?page=3&sort=id&direction=asc`. The data behind the view can be exported by appending `.tsv` to the resource name - `/resource.tsv?page=3&sort=id&direction=asc`. To do this, I use this call in my `.erb`: `add_extension_to_url(request.original_url, '.tsv')` where I have:

```
module ResourceHelper
  def add_extension_to_url(url, extension)
    query_start = url.index('?')
    if query_start.present?
      url.insert(query_start, extension)
    else
      url + extension
    end
  end
end
```

It works, but it's not pretty. Am I missing something like `request.query_string` that gives me what comes after the question mark in the URL?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to

Comment: The idiomatic rails way would be using url helpers (from routing system). Something like `order_path(@order, format: :tsv)`. If you need to preserve existing query string, then something like this should work: `order_path(@order, params.merge(format: :tsv))`. Your url mangling method has one advantage: it's generic. But it's not idiomatic.

Comment: @enragedcamel: no, not that. @sergio: [params.merge is not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271218/params-merge-and-cross-site-scripting), it seems. However, `format: :tsv` looks promising and something I wasn't aware of, so perhaps you could post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

What you call "extension" is "format" in Rails' terms. You can specify format when generating urls using routing system. Something like:

```
order_path(@order, format: :tsv)
```

If you want to preserve an existing query string (with sorting, pagination and whatnot), you can do like this

```
order_path(@order, params.merge(format: :tsv))
```

As for the security concerns, you should be fine as long as you filter `params` so that it only contains expected values. The idiomatic way for this is to use [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) (included in Rails 4).