# URL helpers with string keys deprecated but params uses them as string by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm updating to rails 4.2 and get this deprecation warning:

```
Calling URL helpers with string keys controller, action is deprecated. Use symbols instead.
```

In the controller I am reusing the params to create some links with the same parameters like this:

```
@csv_prms = params
@csv_prms[:format] = :csv
...
```

In the view I do:

```
= link_to 'CSV', report_path(@csv_prms)
```

Now I noticed that by default the *action* and *controller* in params are strings instead of symbols.  Isn't that illogical since they are deprecated to use in URL helpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should not pass through params between requests (see *[params.merge and cross site scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271218/params-merge-and-cross-site-scripting)*), but instead slice the params you need for your new request and merge the new ones:

```
@csv_prms = params.slice(:param1, :param2).merge( format: :csv )
```

This would remove `:controller` and `:action` from the params, which shouldn't be required for creating a link at all, because your `link_to` statements should consistently link to the action *you* want (instead of letting the user fumble around with parameters to let your site create links to whatever).

Comment: Ended up doing:
    @csv_prms = params.except('controller', 'action')
Other params are already checked through permit