# Rails: changing locale and keeping page parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a navbar with links to different languages:

```
<%= link_to t('header.english'), locale: "en" %>
```

The problem is when user tries to switch language on a page which contains additional parameters in the url. Changing locale at this point reloads the page and strips all the additional parameters.

So, how do I pass all the parameters from the current page to the locale switch link?

For example, when

```
/page/new?param1=1&param2=2
```

is open, and user switches the locale,

```
/page/new?locale=en
```

is opened, and both additional parameters are stripped away from the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: THIS IS NOT A GOOD WAY TO DO THIS.** See comments below.

The problem is that you are not passing the current params to `link_to` when you create the locale switcher link.

Change your navbar link to:

```
<%= link_to t('header.english'), params.merge(locale: "en") %>
```

See also: [Add querystring parameters to link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to)

Comment: This will expose a lot of parameters that you may not want to expose, on certain pages, as `params` also includes POST data.

Comment: Sorry the comments above are correct, this is not a good way to do this. The params should be explicitly added.

Answer (score 10):

If you need locale param to stay in all requests it's good to use this approach:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

Comment: Dude, this TOTALLY fixed my problem! Thanks!