# Pretty default url options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes, internationalization

I have two languages which I support with German being the default (See `routes.rb` below).

With my `Post` model I can now create links like so:

```
link_to t('.title'), posts_path(1), locale: I18n.locale
```

This results in these URLs depending on the locale:

- /en/posts/1
- /posts/1

Since German is the default, I have to include the locale, or the links will end up pointing to the German representation. So I have to make sure to include the `locale` parameter in all links to my resources.

To avoid this extra work as well as links pointing to the wrong locale I set up `default_url_options`

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

Credits go to [Rails: changing locale and keeping page parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727609/rails-changing-locale-and-keeping-page-parameters).

My links are more concise now: `link_to t('.title'), posts_path(1)` but the links don't look so nice now anymore:

- /posts?locale=de
- /posts?locale=en

Is there a way to get the non-parameterised versions of the links but using `default_url_options` at the same time.

#### My `routes.rb` for reference:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope '(:locale)/', locale: /en|de/, defaults: {locale: 'de'} do
    root to: 'posts#index'
    resources :posts
  end
end
```