# Pass additional parameters with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have a news page containing several news with pagination. I want to allow the user to view the new's details and when he clicks on a "back" button, the view goes to the page the user was previously on. My idea was to add a parameter to the link_to which brings the user on the show page, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
<%= link_to news_path(new.id, :back_page => params[:page]) do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
<% end %>
```

I would want the url rendered to be something like this: `news/2?back_page=2`. But I always get `news/2`.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here's how `news_path` looks like in my routes: http://pastebin.com/EAhDQyf4

Comment: Could you please show your routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. Make sure the value you give to your additional parameters is something. When I go to the news index page, even though the selected page is the first one, there is no parameter `page=1`. The parameter only appears once click on a different page (or you go to another page and come back to the first one). If you give an additional parameter to the link_to and its value is nothing, the rendered link will be (in my case):

```
<a href="/news/2" />
```

Instead of:

```
<a href="/news/2?back_page=" />
```

So you might get trapped, just like I was.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not a problem of link_to, can you post how `news_path` looks in your routes file?

Ideally above `news_path(new.id, :back_page => params[:page])` should generate path as you expected.

Another way to do would be, but I won't recommend it. Because you should be able to achieve it using path helpers.

```
<%= link_to "something", "#{news_path(new.id)}?back_page=#{params[:page]}" do %>
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @BishopBarber Go to rails console and try following

`app.news_path(new.id, :back_page => 'somepagenumber')` 

This should generate path you are looking for.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the `back_page` parameter is rendered as wanted.

Comment: I found out my problem and I really feel stupid. It's just that when I go to the news index page, the page parameter is not given. It is only given when I browse through pages. So my back_page parameter receives nothing. I thought normally I would still see `back_page=`, that's why I didn't think that would be the problem at first, but it is! Thanks a lot for the help. I wasn't sure how to use link_to, that's why I was looking in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here example:

```
link_to "Nonsense search", searches_path(foo: "bar", baz: "quux")
# => <a href="/searches?foo=bar&baz=quux">Nonsense search</a>
```

Comment: I know, I visited [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to). But I don't see what's wrong with my link_to. Can you explain?