# Issue with passing params in link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble passing a param through a link_to in Rails using the below code:

```
<%= link_to new_registration_path, {:workshop => @workshop.id } do %>
```

When I pry into the controller, the :workshop is not being included in the params (only controller and action).

Is this a strong params issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add querystring parameters to link\_to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to)

Answer (score 1):

The `workshop` param has to be passed to the `new_registration_path` helper instead of passing it to `link_to`, like this:

```
<%= link_to new_registration_path(workshop: @workshop.id) do %>
```

If you want the URL to be like `/something/123` instead of `/something?workshop=123`, you can change how your route is defined on `routes.rb`:

```
get something/:workshop
```

and then you can pass `workshop: 123` to the URL helper.

Comment: Ah okay. I was hoping there was a way to do it without a query string

Comment: If you didn't want to use a query string you could do <%= link_to "/some-registration-path/#{@workshop.id}" do %>   Given that in your config/routes.rb you have something like get "some-registration-path/:workshop_id", to: some_controller#some_method