# Passing arguments in path Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, link-to

I have this in one modal and I need to put some data in my `user_link_path` :

```
DATA = <div id="modal-myvalue"></div> //DATA
```

> DATA = `#<UserLink:0x000055635d4d92a0>`

```
<%= link_to "Delete link", user_link_path(NEED TO PUT THE DATA HERE), class: "btn"%>
```

EDIT, 
CODE :

```
<button type="button" 
    class="delete-link fa fa-trash" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#confirmation" 
    data-linkname="<%=userlink.link.name.truncate(30)%>" 
    data-myvalue="<%=userlink%>">
</button>
```

The modal :

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirmation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sure to delete this link :  <div id="modal-linkname"></div></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <span id="modal-myvalue"></span> <span id="modal-myvar"></span> <span id="modal-bb"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="body__modal-footer">
           <%= link_to "Delete link", user_link_path(NEED TO PUT THE DATA HERE), class: "btn"%>

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my Js :

```
<script>
var ATTRIBUTES = ['linkname', 'myvar', 'bb'];

$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function (e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var modalSelector = $target.data('target');

  ATTRIBUTES.forEach(function (attributeName) {
    var $modalAttribute = $(modalSelector + ' #modal-' + attributeName);
    var dataValue = $target.data(attributeName);

    $modalAttribute.text(dataValue || '');
  });
});</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: To pass data you simply pass them as a key/value pair.  link_to "Delete Link", user_link_path(username: "#{@user.user_name}") etc.

Comment: Hi, @bkunzi01 I need to put the clicked link (class look like :  #<UserLink:0x000055635d4d92a0>) to open the modal, can you explain your issue?

Comment: Please put your script in the question rather than in an external link @BenjaminBarbé.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to

Comment: Are you trying to send HTML-markup to the backend?

Comment: Post edited @SRack