# How do I mark notification as read when clicking on link? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a notification system in my rails app. On my notifications model I have:

message
user_Id
read
link_path

The following code works great for showing me the notifications for the current user, and then showing me the notifications that are read. I'm looping through each of these records where this criteria is true, and then doing a link_to @link do, and then outputting the whole code.

Basically the whole block I can then click on and it will take me to the proper record. That works like a charm.

The default for all new notifications is :read => false.

However, when user clicks on the link, I'm trying to pass :read => true into that record, so that when I come back that particular notification will no longer show, since it's only showing me :read => false notifications.

What is the easiest way to go about this? I've tried wrapping everything in a form_for and trying to pass this value of :read => true into the record, but I can't get that to work. Thoughts?

Controller

```
    @x = Notification.where(:user_id =>  current_user, :read => false)
```

View

```
   <% @x.where(:user_id =>  current_user).each do |notify| %> 

   <% @link = notify.link_path %> 

   <%= link_to @link do %>
   <div class="row notifyrow">
     <div class="col-sm-7">
       <p> <%= notify.message %></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
       <p> <%= time_ago_in_words(notify.created_at )%> ago</p>
     </div>       
   </div>
  <% end %> 
  <% end %>
```

Comment: So all you're trying to do is append `?read=true` to the link?

Comment: I don’t know is that all I need to do? This problem seems real simple and I’m just not sure. Would appending that to the link update the record so that it’s read attribute now had value of true ?

Comment: Appending that to the link would cause the `read` parameter to be send with the GET request, and it would have a value `"true"`. I guess you can just pass `read: true` parameter to the `link_to` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to

Comment: Once you sent the parameter you would need to change your controller action to handle it (performing the DB update).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to want to do is to update the `read` attribute on a particular `Notification` when the user clicks the link. That's absolutely what a Controller method is for. For example, assuming the route for your `notify_link` is something akin to `get '/notifications/:id', to: 'notifications#show'`, you'd do the following:

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @notice = Notification.find(params[:id])
    @notice.update!(read: true)
  end
end
```

That updates the `read` attribute on the record, so when you go back to the main view it will no longer appear in your unread list.

By the way, in your controller you run a query to get all the unread notifications for the current user, and then run `where()` again in your view. It should be sufficient to just do `@x.each` in your view.

**EDIT**

To summarise the comments discussion below, since the linked path doesn't include the `Notification` object ID, you just need to include it in the query parameters. The Rails-generated URL helpers take a hash (following any parameters required to complete the path) and includes them in the query string. So, something like:

```
national_race_path(@national_race.id, notify_id: notify.id)
```

will append the ID as `<whatever_path>?notify_id=1234` and it will be accessible in the controller via `params[:notify_id]`. You'll need to handle what happens if no or invalid ID is passed, etc., but that should give you what you need.

Comment: Ok so the link actually goes to something like  get '/candidates/:id', to: 'candidates#show'. So in this case I would just place the code you suggested in the show method of the candidates controller?

Comment: Yes, it would definitely go in the controller that processes the link. My code snippet assumed the link would include the ID of the notification, but it looks like you are linking to the view of a different kind of model. That's not a big deal, but you'll need some way to look up the original Notification, so you might need to also pass its ID as a parameter on the link.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I'm trying to pass id as parameter to the link like this:


            <% @a = notify.id  %> 

            <% @link = notify.link_path(@a) %>

And it's not working. What am I doing wrong here? If I output @a it does in fact give me the id I want. Just not sure how to pass it through link

Comment: The short answer is to add it to the query string of the URL. Is ``link_path`` a Rails-generated URL helper or what? Let me know and I'll update the answer with info.

Comment: Yes, link_path is a rails generated URL helper. It's                                                                         :link_path => national_race_path(@national_race.id))

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you, you are awesome!