# How to override function new so I can send parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have model Product with has_may :benefits, now in link_to for new benefit I don't know how to send ID of product so I can go with

```
Product.find(params[:id]).benefits.new(...)
```

Normal new method is

```
<%= link_to t('add_new_benefit'), new_admin_benefit_path %>
```

I want to send @product object so I can get id from it.

I wanna send it like this

```
<%= link_to t('add_new_benefit'), new_admin_benefit_path(@product) %>
```

routes.rb

```
...
namespace :admin do
      root "action_logs#index"
      get "toolkit", to: "toolkit#index"
      resources :admins
      resources :products
      ...
      resources :benefits
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to pass `id` as a param. Eg:

```
<%= link_to t('add_new_benefit'), new_admin_benefit_path(product_id: @product.id) %>
```

Many examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695538/add-querystring-parameters-to-link-to)

Comment: And how can I use it in controller? params[product_id] gives me nil

Comment: params[:product_id]