# Sending params along with Ruby method as arguments to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble getting a two part argument to a `link_to` method to work, one of which is a Ruby method, and the other a params.

When I use the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Sort by most active", school_course_path(current_school, :params => "by_most_active") %>
```

I get the error that "can't convert String into Hash".  I have tried to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124862/link-to-send-parameters-along-with-the-url-and-grab-them-on-target-page) in terms of syntax for params, but can't figure out why my :params is getting the error.

Thanks.

**Edit**:

To provide additional context, I have the following nested routes set up:

```
  resources :schools do
    resources :courses 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `school_course_path` which expects a school and a course as its first 2 arguments.  You need to provide it with a course after passing current_school.  You should
also change the `params` part with a different name like `order`. So your link_to should look something like

```
school_course_path(current_school, course, order: 'by_most_active')
```

If you are trying to get the most active courses for `current_school`, you should use `school_courses_path`

```
school_courses_path(current_school, order: 'by_most_active')
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution actually seems very close to what I had in mind - basically, putting in the sort preference alongside the link..and the syntax makes so much sense!  In my `CourseController`, in the `show` action, I currently have `questions = @course.questions.all` .. I was wondering how could I take advantage of `:order` params to fit in right into the query?

Comment: use `questions = @course.questions.order(params[:order])` just make sure that you dont get any sql injection issues when you do this.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I got the error "no such column: most_active", and I think the reason is that I defined `most_active` as scope method in my `Question.rb` model.  Basically, I would like to put  `@course.questions.name_of_scope_method`.. is there a way where I could call the name of the scope method after .questions?

Comment: yes, try `@course.questions.send(params[:order])`.  or you can add a class method which checks `params[:order]` and then call the appropriate scope (this is safer and I prefer to us this than my first suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to link to the show method of the course_controller.  Are you not missing the course object as the second argument to the path helper?

Answer (score 1):

The `:params` option is expecting a hash, not a key, so that you can specify both teh keys and the values. You need something like `:params=> { by_most_active: true }`.

Comment: Thank you - so that was what it meant by "convert to hash".  Solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Sort by most active", school_course_path(:current_school => current_school, :params => "by_most_active") %>
```

and call

```
params["current_school"] and current_school["by_most_active"].
```