# How to Get value of text_field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, textfield

I have a text field as:

```
<%= text_field :search, :class=>'input-xxlarge search-query',:id=>'keyword' %>
```

Then on click of a link I want to pass the value in this text field to a
controller method.
I do not want to use a form and form submit.

I have the link as:

```
<a href ="/home/search" >GO</a>
```

and to this 'search' method I want to pass the text field value....
also to go directly to the page "/home/search" designed to this action "search"

How do I do this???
Thank you...

Comment: I know you said you don't want to use a form. But this is **exactly** what forms are for.

Comment: You can use ajax post on click event of link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read here [link_to send parameters along with the url and grab them on target page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124862/1297435)

```
<%= link_to "Go", '/home/search?param1=value' %>
```

So if you won't use form, you should use jQuery for put value of field into attribute link (href) with parameter.
Example on <kbd>[jsffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/cS6WJ/1/)</kbd>

```
<%= text_field :search, :class=>'input-xxlarge search-query',:id=>'keyword' %>
<%= link_to "Go", '', :id => "searchlink" %>


$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    var word = $(':input[id="keyword"]').val();
    $('a[id="searchlink"]').attr("href","/home/search?param1=" + word.toString());

});
```

and in controller:

```
if params[:param1] == ""
 render :search # or redirect whatever do you want 
else
  param = params[:param1]
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your routes file

```
resources :home do
    member do
        get 'search'
    end
end
```

In your html

```
<div id='parentDiv'>
    <%= text_field :search, nil, :class=>'input-xxlarge search-query',:id=>'keyword' %>
    <%= link_to("GO", '#', :class => 'search-link')
</div>
```

In the javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('div#parentDiv').on('click', '.search-link', function(){
  var search_val = $('#keyword').val().trim();
  if(search_val != ''){
    window.location.href='/home/'+search_val+'/search';
  } else{
    alert('You need to enter some data');
  }
 });
});
```

And in your search action

```
def search
  search_value = params[:id]
  # your code goes here.
end
```

Comment: Are you sure use `params[:id]`, id is integer? `window.location.href='/home/'+search_val+'/search'`? How about when I try search with string?

Comment: @anonymousxxx, params[:id] is not referring to any id. we just get the parameter by using params[:id] as the routes create "search_home GET    /home/:id/search(.:format) home#search". yes you can check it with string also.

Comment: +1 Ok i'm understand, thanks.. I think your answer is better workaround

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...(not tested). This will give you the logic.

```
<%= link_to "Go", "#", onclick: "window.location = \"www.sitename.com/home/search?q=\"+$(\"#keyword\").val()" %>
```