# how to pass argument from form_for method to controller method in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal, when i clicked on the button then this bootstrap model will be called (open popup menu) and pass different-different **offer_id's**.

this popup menu open a form(like edit form), I edited all information then click on **edit button** then only first records is updated.

for example I want to edit information of **offer_id = 1**, when fill all form and submit then **offer_id = 1** is updated **not offer_id = 5**.

so i don't know exactly where am i wrong, and what am i missing..

edit button and model on the same page (**_employee_details.html.erb**)

**edit button**

```
<div class="edit-recr-wrp1"> 
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-pencil-square-o" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal1" data-offer_id="<%= emp['offer_letter_id'] %>" data-employee_id="<%= emp['employee_id'] %>"></button>               
</div>
```

**modal "#exampleModal1"**

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2 class="text-center">Edit <span>Employee Details</span></h2>
        <div class="post-new-job head-border">
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id='success-job' style='display:none;'>Employee Details is successfully added.</div>
            <div class="form-body"> 

                <%= form_for :employee_details, :url =>{:controller => "hr", :action => "update" } do |f| %>                
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                     <div class="mydata1">
                       <%= f.text_field :offer_letter_id, { class: 'form-control', id: 'offer_id-name' } %>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Employee ID</label>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
                        <div class="mydata2">
                          <%= f.text_field :employee_id, { disabled: true, :required => true, placeholder: 'E12345678', class: 'form-control', id: 'employee_id-name' } %>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Bank Account</label>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-university"></i> </span>
                          <%= f.text_field :bank_ac, { :required => true, placeholder: '06464060852634865', class: 'form-control' } %>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Bank IFSC Code</label>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-code"></i> </span>
                          <%= f.text_field :bank_ifsc, { :required => true,  placeholder: 'SBI012356', class: 'form-control' } %>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">End of Date</label>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </span>
                          <%= f.text_field :work_end_date, {  placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY', id: 'datepicker1', class:"datepicker_style" } %>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-male fa-female"></i> </span>
                          <%= f.select :gender, ['Male', 'Female'], { :required => true }, class: "form-control" %>
                        </div> 
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">Spouse Name</label>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> </span>
                          <%= f.text_field :spouse_name, { :required => true, placeholder: 'Father/Mother/Wife name', class: "form-control" } %>
                        </div>
                      </div> <br>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <a><%= f.submit "Edit Employee Details", :class => "btn btn-primary" %></a> 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>                
                <%- end -%>
            </div>      
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // edit employee information
    $('#exampleModal1').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
      var offer_id = button.data('offer_id')
      var employee_id = button.data('employee_id')
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.mydata1 input').val(offer_id)
      modal.find('.mydata2 input').val(employee_id)
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // edit employee information
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });    
    });
</script>
```

**hr_controller.rb**

class HrController < ApplicationController

```
    def new
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.new
    end

    # edit employee information
    def edit
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.find_by(params[:offer_letter_id])
    end

    def create
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.new(employee_params)
        if @employees.save
            redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'
        else
            redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'
        end
    end

    def show
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.find_by(params[:offer_letter_id])

        if @employees.update(employee_params)
            redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'
        else
            redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'
        end
    end

    private

        def employee_params
             params.require(:employee_details).permit(:offer_letter_id, :employee_id, :bank_ac, :bank_ifsc, :spouse_name, :gender, :work_end_date)
        end     
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :hr
  get 'hr/edit'
  post 'hr/update'
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't clear to me. First you say you want to edit order_id 1 and order_id is edited - so whats the error? and secondly it's not clear how and when the partial is rendered. Do you render the partial for each and every element of your orders list?

Comment: My question is when i edit information of offer_id = 4, then update all information of offer_id = 1, not offer_id = 4.  I edit information of offer_id = 4 then should be update only information of offer_id =  4 not offer_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

There are some miss concept on you about edit and update method. you should find by id, i mean it should be like

```
@employees = EmployeeDetail.find(id)
```

and secondly please write a raise in update method to check really form passing the data or only passing the first data thats why its only updated your first column.
in def update  =>

```
raise params.inspect
```

then you will determine yourself params are correct or not, def employee_params method worked or not?

Comment: when i used @employees = EmployeeDetail.find(id) then i got following error. Couldn't find EmployeeDetail with 'id'=

Comment: def update

  @employees = EmployeeDetail.find(params[:id])

  if @employees.update(employee_params)
   redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'

Comment: the error is here :  @employees = EmployeeDetail.find(params[:id])

Comment: can you please give me a snap of the output of raise.  raise params.inspect

Comment: and also give the output => raise EmployeeDetail.first.inspect

Comment: when I tried this "raise params.inspect " then i got following error : RuntimeError in HrController#update  => {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jGesRSAaTUE4bQHmO5W2WPcUvZNDHKu+Kw2B9bDX8vcjFmI1Vq9XY/1lsSqb8XhvnAvAppw4SF5nfcg2Rj13gw==", "employee_details"=>{"offer_letter_id"=>"6", "bank_ac"=>"0000055555", "bank_ifsc"=>"SBI0123456", "work_end_date"=>"09/08/2016", "gender"=>"Female", "spouse_name"=>"Vikash Sharma"}, "commit"=>"Edit Employee Details", "controller"=>"hr", "action"=>"update"}

Comment: when i tried this " raise EmployeeDetail.first.inspect" then i got following error : RuntimeError in HrController#update => #<EmployeeDetail id: 1, offer_letter_id: 1, employee_id: "E36162000", bank_ac: "0123897132798", bank_ifsc: "CITY897312", spouse_name: "Shikha Gupta", gender: "Male", created_at: "2016-10-19 08:59:33", updated_at: "2016-11-07 07:08:55", work_end_date: "2016-11-30">

Comment: data = EmployeeDetail.find_by_offer_letter_id(params[:offer_letter_id])
data.update(employee_params)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
def update
    @employees = EmployeeDetail.find(params[:employee_details][:offer_letter_id])
```

if `offer_letter_id` is your primary key or

```
def update
    @employees = EmployeeDetail.find_by(offer_letter_id: params[:employee_details][:offer_letter_id])
```

in any other case...

Comment: I tried both solution but still problems is not solved, offer_letter_id is not a primary key so i tried first solution then i found following error : "Couldn't find EmployeeDetail with 'id'=6"

Comment: i tried also this : @employees = EmployeeDetail.where("offer_letter_id = ?",params[:employee_details][:offer_letter_id]). then i got following error : "wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)" . Error is showing in this line : "if @employees.update(employee_params)".

Comment: when i tried this : @employees = EmployeeDetail.find_by_offer_letter_id(params[:offer_id]). and passed a value from form_for method like this : "<%= form_for :employee_details, :url =>{:controller => "hr", :action => "update", :offer_id => 2 } do |f| %> ". then record : 2 is successfully updated, but I want to pass this text_field value " <%= text_field :offer_id, { class: 'form-control', id: 'offer_id-name' } %>" instead of "2" (:offer_id=>2).

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468695/how-to-get-value-of-text-field-rails. In this link pass parameter throw link_to or <a> tag. I understand but how to use this concept in form_for method, and jquery funcation. Please help me