# Rails show action where `id` is not explicitly stated in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I have a view that shows a number of products. If a product has an active "deal" on it, a link to that deal is given for that deal that links to the `show` action for that deal, as below.

```
<tr>
    <% @item.inventory_items.each do |p| %>
      <td><%= link_to image_tag("#{p.vendor.image_url}"), vendor_path(p.vendor) %></td>
      <td class="price">$<%= p.price %></td>
      <td>
        <% if Deal.where(:product_code => p.product_code, :vendor_id => p.vendor_id).exists? %>
          <%= link_to "See It!", deal_path(Deal.where(:product_code => p.product_code, :vendor_id => p.vendor_id)) %>

        <% else %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>
       ......
      </td>
</tr>
```

The problem I'm having is that my `show` action for Deal is looking in params for a deal `id`. This deal id isn't really in params, so how can I tell this Deal show action which deal I'm interested in? Thanks in advance! As an aside, my above code feels really verbose and very un-rails-like in my `if` block. If you have any suggestions for it, any advice is much appreciated.

deal/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{@deal.vendor.image}") %>
<%= @deal.vendor.address %>
<%= image_tag(@deal.image) %>
```

Deal show action:

```
def show
    @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
            <%= link_to "See It!", deal_path(Deal.where(:product_code => p.product_code, :vendor_id => p.vendor_id).first) %>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! But why does adding `.first` make the magic happen?

Comment: U need to have an ActiveRecord there.. The Deal.where(:product_code => p.product_code, :vendor_id => p.vendor_id) returns an array of ActiveRecords:)

Comment: Whenever you do a `.where`, it returns an array so you either have to loop through it, or get the first one with `.first`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is definitely not very rails-like.

What you should be able to do is something like this:

```
<tr>
        <% @item.inventory_items.each do |p| %>
          <td><%= link_to image_tag("#{p.vendor.image_url}"), vendor_path(p.vendor) %></td>
          <td class="price">$<%= p.price %></td>
          <td>
            <% if p.deal.exists? %>
              <%= link_to "See It!", deal_path(:id => p.deal.id)) %>

            <% else %>
            <% end %>
          </td>
          <td>
           ......
          </td>
    </tr>
```

Note that you can pass parameters along in a link_to. See this question - [link_to send parameters along with the url and grab them on target page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124862/link-to-send-parameters-along-with-the-url-and-grab-them-on-target-page)

If you're models are setup correctly, you shouldn't have to be doing queries in your views.

Comment: This is ideal, I agree. Part of the reason I haven't done this from the outset is because of the way my associations are setup currently. There are some difficulties outside the scope of this question that have prevented me so far from doing this. Perhaps now is a good time to dig in and try to sort them out. Thanks!

Comment: Associations can definitely be tricky, but once they are setup correctly, you really see the beauty of rails. Take the time to learn them now and it will benefit you in the future.