# Use param attributes in version CarrierWave upload for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, syntax-error, carrierwave

I am new in Ruby and I am trying to pass a parameter in a method of CarrierWave called version. My idea is get the opacity paramater value, but I don't know how to write the code for don't get some Syntax error in ruby.

This is the normal code without parameter opacity:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

   version :big_image, :from_version => :redes_sociales do

    process :resize_to_limit => [860, 860]
    process adjust_quality: (85)
    process :watermark => [0.39, 'g']
  end

  version :medium_image(opacity_value = 0.39), :from_version => :redes_sociales do
    process :resize_to_limit => [536,432]
    process :watermark => [0.39, 'm'] 
  end
end
```

This is how I am trying to rewrite the parameter:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

   version :big_image(opacity_value = 0.39), :from_version => :redes_sociales do

    process :resize_to_limit => [860, 860]
    process adjust_quality: (85)
    process :watermark => [opacity_value, 'g']
  end

  version :medium_image(opacity_value = 0.39), :from_version => :redes_sociales do
    process :resize_to_limit => [536,432]
    process :watermark => [opacity_value, 'm'] 
  end
end
```

Then I could use in controllers or views like:

```
imagen_popup = p.avatar.url(:big_image(0.8))
```

or:

```
<a href="<%= c.picture.avatar.url(:big_image(0.8)) %>"
```

Any suggestion or idea of how to pass the parameter? Thanks

Comment: This may have what your looking for as far as passing values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124862/link-to-send-parameters-along-with-the-url-and-grab-them-on-target-page .

Comment: Your a href link example is missing a closing ")"

Comment: Also if you want to see how Carrierwave's versions work you can see the code here http://www.rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Uploader/Versions#versions-instance_method